# Getting old value from output sheet - Excel POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have an excel workbook which contains (`Input`,`Ouput`,`Calc`) and all sheets are filled previously where input sheet has many input cells and I'm filling the input cells with no issues but when I go to the output sheet to get the new result I'm getting old cells values, each output cell has a formula ex:

Cell `B2` Value `=Calc!F8`

here what I tried :

```
/**
     * ********************************** Insert values into the Excel ********************************************
     */

    File excel = stream2file(Core.getFileDocumentContent(getContext(), ExcelFileParameter1));
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excel);

    XSSFWorkbook hssfWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    XSSFSheet inputSheet = hssfWorkbook.getSheet("Input");

    XSSFRow inputSheetRow;
    XSSFCell inputCell;

    for (int i = 1; i <= inputSheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows() - 1; i++) {

        inputSheetRow = inputSheet.getRow(i);
        inputCell = inputSheetRow.getCell(1);

        switch (i) {
        case 1:
            String date = this.ExcelInputParameter1.getDOB().toString();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yy");
            Date currentdate = sdf.parse(date);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            inputCell.setCellValue(sdf2.format(currentdate));
            break;
        case 2:
            inputCell.setCellValue(this.CountryParameter1.getDescription());
            break;

        }
    }

    fis.close();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(excel);
    hssfWorkbook.write(fos);
    fos.close();


    /**
     * ********************************** Get The output from the Excel ********************************************
     */

    fis = new FileInputStream(excel);
    hssfWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    XSSFSheet outputSheet = hssfWorkbook.getSheet("Output");

    XSSFRow outputSheetRow;
    XSSFCell outputCell;

    for (int i = 1; i <= outputSheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows() - 1; i++) {
        outputSheetRow = outputSheet.getRow(i);
        outputCell = outputSheetRow.getCell(1);

        switch (i) {

        case 1:
            this.ExcelOutputParameter1.setCover_1((int) outputCell.getNumericCellValue());
            break;
        case 2:

            this.ExcelOutputParameter1.setCover_2((int) outputCell.getNumericCellValue());
            break;
        }

    }
    fis.close();

    return this.ExcelOutputParameter1;
    }
```

Also tried to evaluate the cell formula:

```
        outputSheetRow = outputSheet.getRow(i);
        outputCell = outputSheetRow.getCell(1);

        CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(outputCell);
```

But `CellValue` = `[#VALUE!]`, I tried to open the workbook with MS Excel and it has the correct output.

Comment: `apache poi` writes the new values into the workbook but does not evaluating the formulas automatically. This is either the task of `Excel` after opening the workbook file or the task of [FormulaEvaluator](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html). Read about [Formula Evaluation](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html), especially [Recalculation of Formulas](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html#Recalculation+of+Formulas).

Comment: @AxelRichter Thank you, Could you please check the updated question still getting the wrong result.

Comment: Don't set a date value as string in `Excel`. Do `inputCell.setCellValue(currentdate);` instead. `Excel` will be so tolerant to get the date from string in formulas which needs date values but `FormulaEvaluator` will not be so tolerant.

Comment: @Axel thanks its working now